# Is there a way for a Library to know the package name of the application using it?

Tags: java, android, apk, android-library, library-project

Is there a way for any class in a **library** (could be activity, view or any other class that may have access to a "magic" method) to know or inquire the package name of the **application** using it?

If so, how?

It would be great to have this ability at run-time, but having this ability in build/compile time would be good as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Context of the application (you can have that passed into your library in a constructor, for example), you can do this:

```
context.getPackageName();
```

EDIT: definitely not at build/compile time.

Comment: I ended up defining a **static** variable in the library's **base** class activity, and initializing it in the application's **derived** class activity's `onCreate()` with `getApplicationContext().getPackageName()`. Thanks to your idea. Accept +1.